# Map<K,V> back to Map<V,Map<K,V>> after groupingBy value, instead of Map<Obj, List<Entry<K,V>>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, set, java-stream

I'm struggling with maintaining the data structures I want across streaming operations in Java, most probably due to lack of proper comprehension and practice.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3);

            //Group by
            Map <Integer, Long> countGrouped = list.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
            System.out.println("group by value, count " + countGrouped);

            //Sort desc
            Map <Integer, Long> descendingSorted = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            countGrouped.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .forEachOrdered(x -> descendingSorted.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
            System.out.println("sorted " + descendingSorted);

            //filter
            Map <Integer, Long> filtered = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            descendingSorted.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue() >= 2)
                .forEach(x -> filtered.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));;
            System.out.println("filtered " + filtered);

            //Split groups
            Map<Object, List<Entry<Integer, Long>>> groups = filtered.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getValue()));
            System.out.println("grouped " + groups);
    }
}
```

Resulting in

```
group by value, count {1=3, 2=1, 3=4}
sorted {3=4, 1=3, 2=1}
filtered {3=4, 1=3}
grouped {3=[1=3], 4=[3=4]}
```

which is correct, but I'm getting into progressively more abstruse data structures without particular sense, as you can see, finishing in a (wtf?) `Map<Object, List<Entry<Integer, Long>>>` as you can see. While it can be just a `Map<Int, Map<Int, Int>>`.

So the specific question is, how do I transform and contain the data structure outputs resulting from stream operations?

I've seen the Collectors providing transform operations toMap(...), and I suppose this is the way to go, but I'm unable (due to lack of proper knowledge, I think) to get it working.

In this case, seems to me I will greatly helped by a didactic explanation, link to comprehensive resources to get better understanding of streams and functional programming, or stuff like this, more than the actual solution to the particular case (which would be nice for an exercise, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a bit surprising that you have difficulties here, as you’ve already shown the knowledge of all necessary things. You know that `groupingBy` can take another `Collector`, you named the right one, `toMap` already, and you’ve used functions to extract the `Map.Entry` values already.

Combining these things, gives you

```
Map<Long, Map<Integer, Long>> groups = filtered.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getValue(),
        Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue())));
System.out.println("grouped " + groups);
```

To demonstrate the operation better, I changed the input to

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4);
```

which results in

```
grouped {3=[1=3, 4=3], 4=[3=4]}
```

though, there is no point in repeating the counts which are always the same as the outer maps keys. So an alternative would be

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> groups = filtered.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println("grouped " + groups);
```

which leads to

```
grouped {3=[1, 4], 4=[3]}
```

Note that you should not use `forEach`/`forEachOrdered` to `put` into a map. Your intermediate steps should rather be

```
//Sort desc
Map<Integer, Long> descendingSorted = countGrouped.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }, LinkedHashMap::new));
System.out.println("sorted " + descendingSorted);

//filter
Map<Integer, Long> filtered = descendingSorted.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getValue() >= 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }, LinkedHashMap::new));
System.out.println("filtered " + filtered);
```

The `toMap` collector accepting a map factory forces us to provide a merge function, but since our input is already a map which must have distinct keys, I provided an always throwing function here, as something would be seriously wrong, if duplicates show up.

But note that forcing all these operations to collect into new maps is unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. There’s also no point in sorting the entire data first and reduce the amount of data via `filter` afterwards. Filtering first would potentially reduce the work of the sorting step whereas the outcome of the filter operation should not depend on the order.

It’s much better to do the entire operation in a single pipeline

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4);

Map<Integer, Long> countGrouped = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println("group by value, count " + countGrouped);

Map<Long, List<Integer>> groups = countGrouped.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getValue() >= 2)
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println("grouped " + groups);
```

Note that unlike the previous code, now the last grouping operation will also retain the order, which results in

```
grouped {4=[3], 3=[1, 4]}
```

i.e., the groups are sorted by descending count.

Since the count is the key of the resulting map, we can also use an intrinsically sorted map as result type and omit the sorting step:

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> groups = countGrouped.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getValue() >= 2)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<Long>reverseOrder()),
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

The main difference lies in the behavior of the result map *after* the stream operation, e.g. if you insert more elements to it, as the `TreeMap` will insert new keys according to the descending order whereas `LinkedHashMap` will append them to the end, maintaining the insertion order.

Comment: Beatiful, this is the kind of mastery I need. Just a question, whats the specific problem with the foreach to put into map?

Comment: @Greco using streams to modify existing object should be the last resort, when no other solution is possible. Depending on the particular operation, it may impose problems with parallel streams or efficiency but even when not, using foreach may become a habit, blocking the view to the straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `groupingBy` is `public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>>
    groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier)`, but if I understand correct you want only to map the value to the map entry something like:

```
Map<Object, Map.Entry<Integer, Long>> groups = filtered.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, x -> x));
System.out.println("grouped " + groups);
```

Output

```
grouped {3=1=3, 4=3=4}
```